# How can I set a default script for a class in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if it's possible to set a script that will run on all elements of a class, that even if I create an element in this class after the code was executed, the element will have this script in it.

Comment: By `class` do you mean a CSS class, i.e. the `class=""` HTML attribute?

Comment: Rather odd request--can you explain why you want to do this? Maybe use a `MutationObserver` or  write a wrapper function that creates an element of this class and executes your JS along with it.

Comment: Yes - use a DOM `MutationObserver`.

Comment: OK, I'll try to! Thank you all!

Comment: Also try [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).

Comment: Initially sounds like plain delegation

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you mean by "set a script" - add a listener to an event like `click?` - then, you maybe don't need MutationObserver or such as mentioned in the comments, but a function like this:

```js
function addEventListener(eventName, selector, listener) => {
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener(eventName, event => {
    if (event.target.matches(selector)) {
      listener(event);
    }
  });
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
addEventListener('click', '.yourClass', function(event)  {
  // .. your function
});
```

This way (it's acts as if) you would add a click-handler to every `.yourClass`, even to those which got created later.

With [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/) you can do the same very easily:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.yourClass', function(event)  {
  // .. your function
});
```

If you want to react to the *creation* of new elements of your class, you can use the above mentioned [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).